# LSTM - LSTM - future value prediction error

Tags: time, future, prediction, lstm

After some research, I was able to predict the future value using the LSTM code below. I have also attached the Dmd1ahr.csv file in the github link that I am using.

https://github.com/ukeshchawal/hello-world/blob/master/Dmd1ahr.csv

As you all can see below, 90 data points are training sets and 91st to 100th are future value prediction.

[image]

However some of the questions that I still have are:

1. In order to predict these values I had to originally take more than hundred data sets (here, I have taken 500 data sets) which is not exactly what my  primary goal is. Is there a way that given 500 data sets, it will predict the rest 10 or 20 out of sample data points? If yes, will you please write me a sample code where you can just take 500 data points from Dmd1ahr.csv file attached below and it will predict some future values (say 501 to 520) based on those 500 points?
2. The prediction are way off compared to the one who have in your blogs (definitely indicates for parameter tuning - I tried changing epochs, LSTM layers, Activation, optimizer). What other parameter tuning I can do to make it more robust?

Thank you'll in advance.

```
import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas

# By twaking the architecture it could be made more robust
 np.random.seed(7)
 numOfSamples = 500

lengthTrain = 90
 lengthValidation = 100
 look_back = 1 # Can be set higher, in my experiments it made performance worse though
 transientTime = 90 # Time to "burn in" time series

series = pandas.read_csv('Dmd1ahr.csv')

def generateTrainData(series, i, look_back):
     return series[i:look_back+i+1]

trainX = np.stack([generateTrainData(series, i, look_back) for i in range(lengthTrain)])
 testX = np.stack([generateTrainData(series, lengthTrain + i, look_back) for i in range(lengthValidation)])

trainX = trainX.reshape((lengthTrain,look_back+1,1))
 testX = testX.reshape((lengthValidation, look_back + 1, 1))

trainY = trainX[:,1:,:]
 trainX = trainX[:,:-1,:]

testY = testX[:,1:,:]
 testX = testX[:,:-1,:]

############### Build Model ###############

import keras
 from keras.models import Model
 from keras import layers
 from keras import regularizers

inputs = layers.Input(batch_shape=(1,look_back,1), name="main_input")
 inputsAux = layers.Input(batch_shape=(1,look_back,1), name="aux_input")

# this layer makes the actual prediction, i.e. decides if and how much it goes up or down
 x = layers.recurrent.LSTM(300,return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(inputs)
 x = layers.recurrent.LSTM(200,return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(inputs)
 x = layers.recurrent.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(inputs)
 x = layers.recurrent.LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(inputs)
 x = layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(1, activation="linear",
                                                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005),
                                                  activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.005)))(x)

# auxillary input, the current input will be feed directly to the output
 # this way the prediction from the step before will be used as a "base", and the Network just have to
 # learn if it goes a little up or down
 auxX = layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(1,
                                                     kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(value=1),
                                                     bias_initializer='zeros',
                                                     input_shape=(1,1), activation="linear", trainable=False
                                                     ))(inputsAux)

outputs = layers.add([x, auxX], name="main_output")
 model = Model(inputs=[inputs, inputsAux], outputs=outputs)
 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
               loss='mean_squared_error',
               metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
 #model.summary()
 #model.fit({"main_input": trainX, "aux_input": trainX[look_back-1,look_back,:]},{"main_output": trainY}, epochs=4, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
 model.fit({"main_input": trainX, "aux_input": trainX[:,look_back-1,:].reshape(lengthTrain,1,1)},{"main_output": trainY}, epochs=100, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

############### make predictions ###############

burnedInPredictions = np.zeros(transientTime)
 testPredictions = np.zeros(len(testX))
 # burn series in, here use first transitionTime number of samples from test data
 for i in range(transientTime):
     prediction = model.predict([np.array(testX[i, :, 0].reshape(1, look_back, 1)), np.array(testX[i, look_back - 1, 0].reshape(1, 1, 1))])
     testPredictions[i] = prediction[0,0,0]

burnedInPredictions[:] = testPredictions[:transientTime]
 # prediction, now dont use any previous data whatsoever anymore, network just has to run on its own output
 for i in range(transientTime, len(testX)):
     prediction = model.predict([prediction, prediction])
     testPredictions[i] = prediction[0,0,0]

# for plotting reasons
 testPredictions[:np.size(burnedInPredictions)-1] = np.nan

############### plot results ###############
 #import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.plot(testX[:, 0, 0])
 plt.show()
 plt.plot(burnedInPredictions, label = "training")
 plt.plot(testPredictions, label = "prediction")
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```